# vuejs use if statement inside @click event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a link like

```
<a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testModal" @click="platform.os.family == 'iOS' ? showSettingiOS() : showSetting()">Test</a>
```

I want to add if statement based on device & change function name. I have tried as

```
@click="platform.os.family == 'iOS' ? showSettingiOS() : showSetting()"
```

and

```
@click="platform.os.family == 'iOS' ? 'showSettingiOS()' : 'showSetting()'"
```

nothing worked. My `platform` object not usable inside function this is why I am trying using at href. What I am doing wrong

Comment: What is `platform` meant to be?

Comment: I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/platform for detecting platform

Comment: Ok, so how are you assigning it to your Vue / component instance's `platform` property for use in the template?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by _"My `platform` object not usable inside function"_?

Comment: @Phil Thanks for your effort. I have found a solution. However `platform` was loaded in parent component but not working in iOS only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed finally. I use

```
computed: {
    platform: () => platform,
},
```

at my component hooks & working fine now. However without it `platform` working everywhere but not working on only in iOS webview.

Answer (score 3):

For complex, conditional logic, you should probably use a method instead of relying on inline evaluation:

```html
<a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testModal" @click="click">Test</a>
```

```js
methods: {
  click() {
    if (this.platform.os.family === 'iOS') {
      this.showSettingiOS();
    } 
    else {
      this.showSetting();
    }
  },

  showSettingiOS() {
    
  },
  showSetting() {
    
  }
}
```

#### Edit

If the instance of `platform` is of the parent's, you could [`provide`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject) it to the child component:

```js
// Parent
{
  provide() {
    return {
      platform
    }
  }
}

// Child    
{
  inject: [ 'platform' ]
}
```